# не отображаются элементы gluon JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Я подключился библиотеку gluon (charm-glisten-4.4.1) и отрисовываю на сцене при помощи fxml элементы gluon (к примеру TextField), но вместа gluon TextField при запуске программы у меня прорисовывается стандартный, как правильно вызывать элементы библиотек gluon?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <BorderPane layoutX="69.0" layoutY="46.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <top>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </top>
...
```

хочу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выдает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код контроллера бы или воспроизводимый пример полностью.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю нужно сделть как-то так:

В контроллере:

```
public class YourController {
   @FXML 
   private TextField textfield;
}
```

в FXML:

```
<children>
  <TextField fx:id="textfield"/>
</children>
```

Comment: не очень понимаю как это должно сработать, ведь за прорисовку элементов fxml файл все же отвечает, но когда я решил добавить повторно в тот же fxml объект `com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField` и присвоить ему id, то на айдишник выдает ошибку - `Cannot set com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField to field 'description'`, пока причину не понял

Comment: причина в том чо какое-то поле дескрипшен не может быть текстовым, почему я тоже не знаю

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760039/com-gluonhq-charm-glisten-control-textfield-does-not-exist вот вроде бы тоже описано (там вопрос о другом но шаги есть)

Comment: @VladZherihov может есть минипроект на гите который можно было бы в нетбинсе запустить?